# SQL query to select people interviewed more than once in a year

Tags: sql, ms-access

first of all this query will be done in access, I'm trying to find details of people who have been interviewed more than once in a specific year. 
It needs to be multi tabled, to both sort out people who have been interviewed more than once in 2013, and the details of those people.

Example

Tables are as follows:

> ***Interview***
>
> | ID | InterviewDate |
>
> | 123|  13-12-04 |
>   | 789|  14-01-10|
>   | 123|  13-12-21 |
>
> ***Person***
>
> | ID | NAME | NUMBER | LOCATION |
>
> | 123|  John| 128231 | USA
>   | 789|  Max | 123556 | Europe

So the list is a bit larger, but ideally I want to be able to make a query that will count whose had an interview more than once in 2013 and their details from another table.

I have this query which apparently works but I'm sure there's a better way to show it as this may have some flaws.

```
SELECT P.ID, Name, Number, Location, COUNT(year(InterviewDate) AS InterviewNo, Year(InterviewDate) AS Year
FROM Person AS P INNERJOIN Interview as I ON P.ID = I.ID
GROUP BY P.ID, Name, Number, Location, Year(InteviewDate)
HAVING COUNT(Year(InterviewDate)) > 1 AND Year(InterviewDate)='2013'
```

I feel like the year(InterviewDate) is all wrong, would I be able to get the same result without using that exact phrase? Maybe using a sub-query.

Thank you.

Comment: `feel like the year(InterviewDate) is all wrong`..What does that mean?

Comment: That query looks fine. Why do you want to change it if it produces your desired results effectively? `[it] apparently works` only means that you don't understand what's going on. So stop changing stuff.

Comment: I suspect OP doesn't like the fact the grouping and filtering is being done after the join. I haven't measured it, but it feels cleaner to group and filter before the join.

Comment: Yeah, sorry should have been more clear on that, thanks Karl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My access syntax is probably a little off, but I think you are asking fro something like:

```
SELECT P.ID
      ,Name
      ,Number
      ,Location
      ,InterviewNo
  FROM Person P 
       INNER JOIN 
       (SELECT ID
              ,COUNT(1) AS InterviewNo
          FROM Interview 
         WHERE Year(InterviewDate) = 2013
         GROUP BY ID
        HAVING COUNT(1)> 1) I ON P.ID=I.ID
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but when I input that it doesn't recognize Count(1) InterviewNo as an object, if I remove Count(1) then the tables show but no data is recorded. Thanks

Comment: You need an AS to alias in Access apparently. Count(1) AS InterviewNo in Access.

Comment: Sorry to ask for your help again Karl, but when I run it as it is, it has the "Enter Parameter Value" box with the InterviewDate as the input. This is after making an alias in the first SELECT query and the one after Count(1) in the sub-query.

Comment: No, actually if you read the message carefully it probably says, " "Enter Parameter Value" box with the InteviewDate as the input." So you can just fix my typo and it'll work. I had to actually create an Access DB do see the message.

Comment: AND it works! Thank you so much for all your help Karl, and thanks for all the trouble you went to, I'll use this as a learning lesson. :)